# Prove for all the ordinals α and β that ( α∗β, ∈) ≃ (α x β, <)

Tags: ordinals

Prove for all the ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that ( $\alpha * \beta$, $\in$) $\simeq$ ($\alpha$ x $\beta$, <), where  < is an antilexicographic device on $\alpha$ x $\beta$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: Which definition of $\alpha \beta$ are you using? Some prefer to first prove that every well-order is order-isomorphic to a unique ordinal, and $define$ $ \alpha \beta$ as the ordinal isomorphuc to the reverse-lex order on  $\alpha \times  \beta$. Others prefer  different def'ns, e.g. a recursive def'n.

Comment: In the case you're using the recursive definition of multiplication, the fact that $(\alpha+\beta,<)$ is isomorphic to $(\alpha,<)\tilde{+}(\beta,<)$ helps, where $\tilde{+}$ is linear order addition: http://jdh.hamkins.org/an-algebra-of-orders/